# Google Sheets - UrlFetchApp/ GetContentText - working with data?

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have managed to receive HTTP response from a protected webpage by using UrlFetchApp and passing credentials/cookie etc. This correctly returns the data and I have been able to convert to a blob and download as a text file.

However, what I want to do is extract the relevant table from the HTML file, in exactly the same way as the ImportHTML() function works in google sheets. Can anyone give me some hints on this? I have tried parsing using xml service but it doesn't like the data, i'm hoping there is a simpler way?

Cheers

Comment: No simpler way. You'd need to write  your own program replicating it's  functionality.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this workaround is useful for your situation, if you want to use ``ImportHTML()``, for example, how about retrieving the table by ``ImportHTML()`` from HTML deployed using Web Apps? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Thanks Tanaike! I did think about that too but was hoping there was a simpler way. Might be the solution for now!